# We know how expensive we are

Tags: syntactic-analysis, ambiguity, questions, subordinate-clauses

> We know how expensive we are.

I cannot for the life of me decide if this is supposed to be interpreted as a complement clause or an embedded question or what.

My thought process so far is that it couldn't be a reported question (for semantic reasons) or fused relative ("how" here doesn't work as a relative pronoun) at all. Sources I've checked so far have been ambiguous about how small or vast a category "complement clause" can encompass, for example, with some including reported questions *in* the category of verbal complements (Mark Newson et al., 2006) and some not doing so.

---

**Edit:**
I'll add the context in which the sentence originally appeared, after talking with my student. I believe this doesn't fundamentally change anything, but perhaps pushes it towards an interrogative interpretation:

> You may complain about our high prices, but unlike *a certain competitor*, we have informed you that the increase would be 15%, so at least we know how expensive we are.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148330/discussion-on-question-by-rm-translations-we-know-how-expensive-we-are); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Short answer (tl:dr):**

In the Original Poster's example, the subordinate finite clause *how expensive we are* is syntactically ambiguous and could be either interrogative or exclamative.

---

**Full answer**:

> 1. We know how expensive we are.

The fact that the analysis of this sentence is vexing the Original Poster is not surprising because it is syntactically and semantically ambiguous. And furthermore, as they note, the term *complement clause* seems to be widely used but poorly defined.

Let's do away with this pernicious term here.

Setting aside relative clauses and comparative clauses, both of which have their own peculiar structures, we can analyse finite subordinate clauses as belonging to one of four syntactic clause types:

- declarative
- closed interrogative
- open interrogative
- exclamative

These are the subordinate equivalents of the five main clause types, apart from that there is no subordinate form for imperatives. We can, of course, use different constructions to convey a similar sort of meaning to imperatives:

- She demanded that we leave
- It was imperative we should leave

Note that despite denoting commands or indicating a compulsion to act, the examples above use straightforward declarative subordinate clauses in terms of their syntax. And syntax is what we're looking at today.

These four types of finite subordinate clause can partake in all kinds of grammatical relations. For example, they can be the Subjects of main clauses. However, as the term *subordinate* may convey, they most often appear as the Complements of other words or phrases:

2. We know **[that] you stole the cookies**.  <sup>declarative</sup>
3. We know **whether you stole the cookies**. <sup>closed interrogative</sup>
4. We know **which cookies you stole**. <sup>open interrogative</sup>
5. We know **what a cookie thief you are**. <sup>exclamative</sup>

In (2-5) above, you can see these four clause types all occurring as the Complement of the verb *know*. In this particular case we are interested in subordinate open interrogatives like (4) and subordinate exclamative as in (5).

Both subordinate interrogatives and subordinate exclamatives share some features. They both, for example, have a *wh*-phrase which must occur in clause initial position. And if that *wh*-phrase is not the subject of the clause, or part of the subject of the clause, they have a gap inside the nucleus of the clause which we identify with that *wh*-phrase. We could represent them like this:

6. We know **which cookies**<sub>1</sub> [you stole ___<sub>1</sub>]
7. We know **what a cookie thief**<sub>1</sub> [you are ___<sub>1</sub>]

The small subscript '1' there shows that the *wh*-phrase and the gap refer to the same things. We could alternatively represent the sentences like this:

8. We know **which cookies** [you stole <s>which cookies</s>]
9. We know **what a cookie thief** [you are <s>such a cookie thief</s>]

The *wh*-words that occur in subordinate interrogatives are interrogative words, and they can represent all types of word categories and correspond to phrases carrying out many different types of syntactic functions. They have many forms: *who, which, what, where, when, why, how* and so forth. In contrast, the *wh*-words in subordinate exclamatives are not interrogative words, and are limited to the words *how* and *what*. And far from having a wide range of meanings, both of these words indicate degree or extent.

These two exclamative *wh*-words are homophonous with the interrogative words *what* and *how*. Luckily in the case of *what*, the meaning is clearly different. Exclamative *what*  indicates the degree or extent of something whilst interrogative *what* substitutes for a determiner or a noun phrase and is the unconstrained version of *which*:

- What books did you want?
- Which books did you want? (limited selection available)

Also the grammar can help us disambiguate in the case of *what*. Exclamative *what* modifies a whole noun phrase, but when interrogative *what* occurs within an NP, it functions as Determiner. For this reason, if the head of the noun phrase is a singular, countable noun, we will see an article or other determiner between an exclamative *what* and the noun. However, in the case of the interrogative, the word *what* **is** the Determiner:

10. I know **what tyrant** you deposed. (interrogative)
11. I know **what a tyrant** you deposed. (exclamative)

Like exclamative *what*, exclamative *how* is homophonous with interrogative *how*. However, interrogative and exclamative *how* are similar in meaning and also carry out a similar range of syntactic functions. This means that interrogative and exclamative *how* are sometimes difficult or impossible to disambiguate without any special intonation. Thus the following sentence is ambiguous:

12. My wife noted **how much I had spent**.

In the sentence above, the clause in bold could be either interrogative or exclamative. In the first case the sentence would mean:

> My wife made a mental note of the answer to the question '*How much did my husband spend?*'

And in this case the answer might be  one euro, or a million euros. In the exclamative case, however, the meaning would be:

> My wife made a mental note: '*How much my husband has spent!*'

And in this case we don't know whether this is a good or a bad thing, but we do know that the amount of money was quite a lot and that it was surprising or noteworthy.

---

**The Original Poster's question**

- We know how expensive we are.

The sentence above is syntactically ambiguous. The finite subordinate clause functioning as the Complement of the verb *know* could be either an open interrogative clause or an exclamative clause. The interrogative version means something like:

13. We know the answer to the question "*How expensive are we?*"

The exclamative version means something like:

14. We appreciate to what a considerable degree we are expensive.

Comment: You wrote: "if the head noun is singular, we will see an article or other determiner between an exclamative what and the noun." However, wouldn't that fail when the head noun is noncount? E.g.: "I know what pain you've endured." Surely this "what" "indicates the degree or extent of something" (exclamative) and isn't "the unconstrained version of which" (interrogative), right?

Comment: @MarcInManhattan Yes, of course. It's only sing count nouns that require a Determiner. I often wish that we had separate terms for the grammatical non-plural form of a noun and the semantic property of being singular/a single thing along with all the attendant grammatical stuff that being a semantically singular noun entailed.

Comment: @MarcInManhattan Have edited. Is that clearer?

Comment: Yes, sometimes I think that the terminology is already crazy, but you're right, a few more terms would often be useful. Thanks!

Comment: You may complain about our high prices [our company], but unlike a certain competitor, we have informed you that the increase would be 15%, so at least we know how expensive we are [how expensive the prices at/from our company are]. How is that ambiguous?

Comment: @Lambie Look at the timeline and edit date.

Comment: Yes, I realize is was added post facto.

Answer (score 1):

The Cambridge Grammar of the English language p978 has the following in a section titled 'Survey of constructions containing subordinate interrogatives'.

> (d) Internal complement licensed by the matrix verb
>
> [23]
>
> i We’ll [establish **what caused the malfunction**].
>
> ii We [investigated **whether the contract is valid**].
>
> [24]
>
> i *ascertain care check consider decide determine disclose discover establish estimate forget guess indicate inform judge know lean mind notice observe predict prove realise recall remember say see show tell think*
>
> ii *ask concern2 inquire investigate ponder*
>
> *Concern*2 means “be about”: The debate concerned how best to contain inflation.
>
> The verbs in [i] license declaratives as well as interrogatives, while
> those in [ii] do not: compare *We’ll establish that the contract is
> valid* and ∗*We investigated that the contract is valid*. The verbs
> that exclude declaratives include the verbs of asking (interpreted
> broadly enough to include wonder), but they are not limited to these.

*How* can head a fused relative as in

> That's not [**how** I wanted it done].  [**the way**...]

but here we could not insert *the way...*, so it's definitely an interrogative if the choice is between a fused relative or an interrogative. However, as pointed out by Araucaria, it could also be interpreted as an excalmative - the heads allowing these being generally the same as those allowing interrogatives, and the form of the subordinate clause also being the same for the clause in question.

Comment: Aherm, apart from that it's not definitely an interrogative! ;-) It may well be exclamative. (See my answer)

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. Yep, I agree.